How to migrate Sitecore forms to XM Cloud?
We have Sitecore forms in Sitecore 9.3 application. Now client wants to migrate application from SC 9.3 to XM Cloud. As Sitecore forms is not available in XM Cloud and not compatible with XM Cloud forms, can you please guide us how to migrate Sitecore forms to XM Cloud? What would be the replacement of SC 9.3 Forms DB in XM cloud? Any thoughts please?

The short answer is, you can't do this.
XM Cloud  Forms is a brand new SaaS application that is very different from the MVC Sitecore Forms solution.
If it based on Send and you build the forms in the application. There is no automated migration path.

Thanks for the details. So all the historical data what we have in Sitecore 9.3 Forms DB will be lost if we could not migrate? Any other way to reuse the forms data in XM cloud?

No XM Cloud does not store antmything like that

As Richard Seal said above, the answer is no.
Also, when going Composable with Sitecore Saas Products, we need to unlearn a number of things to learn new things. Example, with XM Cloud Forms, we do not have a Forms Database anymore to store the data, and when the XM Cloud Form is submitted, the data will need to be connected through webhooks to another Saas Application, either to go to CDP and create a Customer contact or to Send or if the Client has SalesForce, we can connect to an API to send data directly to SalesForce. This can be done by using Sitecore Connect, to connect the various applications, or via writing Middleware - e.g. an Azure Function - to take care of the needful.
Now, what about the existing data of the client, when they were using Sitecore Forms in their current environment?
Well again, either writing a utility to extract their data and move it to the newer SaaS product - e.g. if it is CDP, Batch Import can be used.
Hope this helps!

Thank you Varun for the details. One question. Can “on premise sql custom DB” be the end target to post the data from XM Cloud forms?

Yes, I mean from an implementation standpoint, you might need to write a Middleware - Azure Function or API - which connects to that On Premise Custom SQL DB, and store the data there. In case there are some internal applications which are using that On prem custom DB, great, if not, the data will be in a Silo. In that case, its good to send this data to SF or CDP.

Thank you Varun
